# DBCP - does it support multi-threading?

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I see in many places like: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html that dbcp is not multi-threaded and it is slow etc.

However they did release a new version last year. Does anyone know if the known issues as mentioned above are resolved or not?

I am currently using c3p0 but find it troubling in some cases (e.g. I run 10 threads with max connection pool size set to 300 and within a few minutes I see almost all the 300 connections open...).

Thanks,

Yair

Answer (score 0):

DBCP 1.4 is a big improvement over 1.2, so I'd be wary of older discussions concerning DBCP's shortcomings.

Some people get better performance out of c3p0, some get better out of DBCP. Connection pools are highly sensitive to configure and application usage patterns, and I suspect each of these libraries is better at different things.